# Using servlet getparameter auto increment

Tags: jsp, servlets

**I have been trying to pass the textbox from jsp to servlet Using htmlform ,i can get the values below like this**

```
String member1=request.getParameter("member1");
string member2=request.getParameter("member2");
        String member3=request.getParameter("member3");
        String member4=request.getParameter("member4");
        String member5=request.getParameter("member5");
        String member6=request.getParameter("member6");
        String member7=request.getParameter("member7");
        String member10=request.getParameter("member10");
        String member8=request.getParameter("member8");
        String member9=request.getParameter("member9");
```

If i use looping concept like below i could not get values. Anyone please me out.

```
    String member="member";
    for(int i=1;i<size;i++){
        String c=Integer.toString(i);
        String member1 = member.concat(c);
        member1=request.getParameter(member1);
    }
```

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Using StringBuilder for this purpose will be faster and more readable.

```
    String member = "member";
    for(int i=1;i<size;i++){
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder (String.valueOf(member));
        sb.append(i);
        String query = sb.toString();
        member1=request.getParameter(query);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `ArrayList` or `String` or `HashMap` (etc) array to store the list of member values. Below is the example of storing the variables in `ArrayList`

```
List<String> members = new ArrayList<String>(); // To store the member values
String member = "member";

for(int i=1;i<size;i++){
    members.add(request.getParameter(member+i));
}
```

Comment: Thanks lot man i tried your code also but in this list again split the values and store database is double work for me anyway Thanks for sharing